# how to get the value from custom lookup cmp

Tags: lightning-web-components

Trying to retrieve the selected value from custom lookup input:

```
        <c-custom-lookup  
              objectname="contact"  
              searchfield="Name" 
              value={value}
              onchange={handleChange}
              data-id="searchField"
              icon-name="standard:contact">
        </c-custom-lookup>

     handleChange(event){
           const searchOption = event.detail.value;
           console.log('Search value=' + searchOption);
           this.searchValue = searchOption;
        
       }
```

Tried both target.value and detail.value but the value is not being retrieved from HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c-custom-lookup` component should provide the value:

```
const record = { Id: 'ABC', Name: 'XYZ', ... };
const evt = new CustomEvent('change', { detail: { record } }
```

Then you can access it as you expect:

```
handleChange(event) {
  let recordId = event.detail.record.Id; // etc...
```